# Expected max number of picks for discrete uniform variables

Tags: probability

X is a random variable with equal probability to be any of the values 1,2,3...n. With s number of trials, where s is much larger than n, we count how many times each value of X appears. What is the expected max for the number of times a value appears. What is the distribution of this max?

For instance, simulation shows that n=10, s=1000 gives roughly 115.6 as the expected max.
Code used for simulation:

```
outcomes = []
while True:
    d = {i: 0 for i in range(10)}
    for _ in range(1000):
        d[random.randint(0, 9)] += 1
    outcomes.append(max(d.values()))
    print(sum(outcomes) / len(outcomes))
```

Comment: For $n=2$ the expected value is $\frac s2 + {s \choose s/2}\frac{s}{2^{s+1}}$ if $s$ is even and $\frac s2 + {s-1 \choose (s-1)/2}\frac{s}{2^{s}}$ if $s$ is odd.  For large $s$ this is about   $\frac s2 +\sqrt{\frac{s}{2\pi}}$ and the distribution is close to a shifted half-normal.  For larger $n$ you will still have $\frac{s}{n}$ plus something times $\sqrt{s}$, though I have forgotten what the something is

Comment: This is well known and non trivial problem. See eg [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146418/expectation-of-maximum-of-uniform-multinomial-distribution) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104948/distribution-of-maximum-of-a-uniform-multinomial-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1).